# Trigger para que no actualice el stock cuando es < 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Hola quiero hacer un trigger que cuando el stock de mi inventario se menor o igual a 0 ya no me permita vender mas producto pero me los sigue restando igualmente

```
create trigger NoProductos0a on InventarioProducto for update 
as 
declare @cantidad int
select @cantidad = count(InventarioProducto.Cantidad) from InventarioProducto
if (@cantidad<0)
begin
print 'No se puede realizar la venta, supera la cantidad existente del producto.' 
end
```

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente

```
InventarioProducto
IdProducto int identity(1,1)
Nom_Producto varchar(50)
Precio_Uni decimal(18,2)
Cantidad int
```

El valor de Cantidad es 5 y trato que al ejecutar este comando no me de resultado -1

```
update InventarioProducto set Cantidad-=6 where IdProducto=1
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras la estructura de tu tabla y el codigo del update que estas tratando de hacer.  Creo que lo que intentas se podria hacer con un INSTEAD OF trigger, pero no estoy seguro que esa sea la mejor forma.  Talvez seria mejor verificar la cantidad antes de hacer el update, o crear un CHECK constraint que no permita que la cantidad sea menor que 0

Comment: Ya puse la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Hola llegaste a resolver ese problema si es asi podrias ayudarme te paso mi fb: https://www.facebook.com/fernando.mimbelaaranda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunas observaciones

- Para efectivamente detener la actualización, no alcanza con hacer un `print` debes "emitir" un error. Esto se logra con [`RAISEERROR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), en tu caso deberías el print por: `RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la venta, supera la cantidad existente del producto.' ,10,1)`, pero si además, tu aplicación no esta controlando el error y haciendo un `ROLLBACK` explícito habría que agregar un `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.
- No entiendo muy bien está lógica: `select @cantidad = count(InventarioProducto.Cantidad) from InventarioProducto`, ¿Por que el `COUNT`?¿Estás actualizando uno o más registros?, Te recomiendo además ir directamente a ver el valor en `INSERTED`, esta es una vista que se tiene en los triggers y que contiene los registros luego de la actualización, por lo que es mejor hacer `SELECT @cantidad = count(Cantidad) FROM INSERTED` o `SELECT @cantidad = Cantidad FROM INSERTED`, este último si solo estás actualizando una fila.
- Por último, no está de más recordar, que los triggers en SQLServer son por lote, es decir se ejecutan una única vez independientemente si tu `UPDATE` es de un registro o de varios, esto te lo comento por que el trigger pareciera asumir que solo actualizarán una única fila. Tenlo en cuenta, por que la lógica actual no parece estar preparada para un `UPDATE` masivo de la tabla, que siempre podremos hacer por otros medios más allá de la aplicación, si no se quiere contemplar esto, lo que se suele hacer es verificar cuantas filas se están actualizando y emitir otro error si son más de las que la lógica del trigger está en condiciones de manejar.
- Y ahora sí, lo último de lo último, ¿sabes que está verificación que parece bien sencilla: que una determinada columna no tenga un valor menor a 0, podrías eventualmente hacerla por medio de un [`CHECK`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017), sin necesidad de programar un trigger?

Edita tu trigger con el siguiente código:

```
IF (SELECT Cantidad FROM INSERTED) < 0 BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la venta, supera la cantidad existente del producto.',10,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Si solo quiero que se actualice una fila y ya quite el COUNT pero igual me los resta, me sale el mensaje de error pero siempre me lo resta

Comment: @EduardoNoyola, si te está mostrando el  mensaje de error del `RAISEERROR` (no el del print), la transacción debiera volver para atrás, es decir no puede estar haciendote el `UPDATE` de `InventarioProducto `.  Agrega a tu pregunta la sentencia de `UPDATE` que estás realizando.

Comment: @EduardoNoyola, te pasé en limpio el código del trigger, pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: Asi tengo el codigo ahorita
create trigger NoProductos0t on InventarioProducto for update 
as 
IF (SELECT Cantidad FROM INSERTED) < 0 BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la venta, supera la cantidad existente del producto.',10,1)
END

Comment: Y ejecuto esto: update InventarioProducto set Cantidad-=6 where IdProducto=1

Comment: El valor de Cantidad es 5 y me lo resta a -1

Comment: @EduardoNoyola `InventarioProducto` puede tener más de un registro por `IdProducto`?

Comment: No, solo puede haber un IdProducto por cada producto

Comment: Efectivamente, si no estás controlando el error por la aplicación, olvidé un detalle muy importante, hay que agregar un  `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` luego del `RAISEERROR`,

Comment: GRACIAASSSS
ya no ejecuta el comando ya sale correctamente, gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Es que a menos que le mandes un número negativo te va a seguir restando por que le dices que si cantidad es menor a 0 te mande el mensaje, haz esto:

```
create trigger NoProductos0a on InventarioProducto for update 
as 
declare @cantidad int
select @cantidad = count(InventarioProducto.Cantidad) from InventarioProducto
if (@cantidad<=0)
begin
print 'No se puede realizar la venta, supera la cantidad existente del producto.' 
end
```

Cambia el if por un menor o igual a 0

Comment: Me lo sigue restando

Comment: Que te da de resultado en todo caso el @cantidad?

Comment: En esa tabla llamada InventarioProducto tengo un campo Cantidad que es el stock con valor = 5
Y cuando ejecuto el comando 
update InventarioProducto set Cantidad-=6 where IdProducto=1 
me lo resta y me aparece como -1

Comment: Creo que ya vi el detalle, para que haces el count? se supone que el campo InventarioProducto.Cantidad ya trae el valor de tu stock no? si es así quitale el count

Comment: Ya quite el count y me imprime el error pero siempre me lo sigue restando

Comment: Ese es tu tigger completo? no le falta nada?

Comment: Si ya esta completo pero pasa el mismo error